# what 's wrong with this "simple" code

Tags: c

I'm trying to do a really simple task.

1. Check if a file exists
2. If not, make it

the files should be named like : M0 M1 M2 and so on.
Here's the code that I've written. It works for `M0` after that I get `segmentation fault error`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (){

    unsigned int fileIndex=0;
    char* fileName="M0";
    FILE* recordFile = NULL;
    while((access(fileName,F_OK)!=-1)) {
        fileIndex++;
        sprintf(fileName,"M%d",fileIndex);
        printf("%s\n",fileName);
    }

    recordFile = fopen(fileName,"wb+");

    fclose(recordFile);
    return 0;
}
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong here? thanks in advance!

Comment: The duplicate question is automatically linked right above your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing into a string literal, which is usually stored in read-only memory.

```
 char* fileName="M0";
```

Change it to an array that is a copy of the literal to fix the immediate problem.

```
char fileName[]="M0";
```

However, you will probably start running into storage issues if you go above `10`, so it is probably better to allocate a larger buffer to accomodate larger filename lengths.

```
char fileName[10] = "M0";
```

Comment: so what your solution suggestion ?

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm not allowed to accept it, until 8 min

Comment: @Engine, You are very welcome. By the way, you might notice this happening often, where someone will post an answer and then edit it :)